# Condense 4 or more line breaks into 3 line breaks

Tags: php, regex

Thanks for helping me out! I've searched all over the internet and could not find an answer to what I'm looking for.

I have a comment feature and I don't want users to be able to have more than 2 empty lines between sentences. Example:

```
1st Line - 1 break
2nd Line - 2 breaks

3rd Line - 3 breaks


4th Line - 4 breaks



5th Line - 5 breaks




6th Line
```

should condense down to:

```
1st Line - 1 break
2nd Line - 2 breaks

3rd Line - 3 breaks


4th Line - 4 breaks


5th Line - 5 breaks


6th Line
```

The solution also needs to remove line breaks that are surrounded by spaces and tabs so users can't get around the line break condensing.

I tried the following, but it ends up just removing all line breaks except the break after the sentence:

```php
$text = preg_replace("/(\s*\R\s*)/", "\n", $text);

$text = preg_replace("/\R{3,}/", "\n\n\n", $text);


Results in:

1st Line - 1 break
2nd Line - 2 breaks
3rd Line - 3 breaks
4th Line - 4 breaks
5th Line - 5 breaks
6th Line
```

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks for taking the time to view my question. Have a great day!

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/oGyzyZ/2

Comment: Thanks @splash58. Yes the last regex works, but it doesn't account for newlines with spaces/tabs around it, where the user could get away with more than 2 breaks between sentences.

Comment: @PHPMYSQLDEV: Use `$str = preg_replace('/(?:\h*\R){3,}/', '\n\n', $str);` or check: https://regex101.com/r/oGyzyZ/3

Comment: @anubhava, thanks for your answer. It's almost working :)  It seems to remove all spaces even before/after text (and not just line breaks), as well as removing multiple spaces between characters. I'd like to be able to preserve the ability to add multiple spaces before text and in between text for any specific reason the user might have in order to format their message the way they'd like. Thanks!

Comment: @PHPMYSQLDEV: It will only remove trailing spaces before line break but other spaces between characters or leading whitespaces in a non-empty line will remain. You can check output in demo link.

Comment: Ah I see @anubhava. It does work! It is storing it properly in the database. Thanks! I'll mark as correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use this php regex:

```
$str = preg_replace('/(?:\h*\R){3,}/', '\n\n\n', $str);
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oGyzyZ/5)

This regex matches using

- `(?:\h*\R)`: Matches 0 or more horizontal whitespaces followed by any line break. `(?:...)` is for a non-capturing group.
- `(?:\h*\R){3,}`: Matches 3 or more occurrences of grouped expression

Comment: just one tiny thing: the replacement should be 3 newlines instead of 2 (per the question). Thanks!

Comment: Hi @anubhava, it should actually be {3,} and '\n\n\n'. Thanks! :)